# How to fix this COMException - "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154"

Tags: vb.net, exception, controls, comexception

I have a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) project, and it works fine on my deveelopment machine (naturally :-)), but on two different computers I tested on, I get the following error, when I attempt to open a specific form. All three computers (including my dev machine, which works) are Windows 7 64-bit machines, two Professional Edition (including mine) and the third is Home Basic.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with [Windows Media Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player) or Adobe SWF player controls I have inserted. Here is the error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
at WizoDesktop.FormPlayer.c4cf84dbbc00986a0b43ce266bdec20d7()
at WizoDesktop.FormPlayer..ctor()
at A.c237671a6e3a2745adc05bbdc0150506d.cff280b017b22ca351191a6adb2feeae4()
at System.Windows.Forms.Command.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Assuming you've set the Platform target set to x86, this error means nothing more than that the ActiveX control isn't installed on that machine.  Hundreds of questions about this error code already.

Comment: I have searched through StackOverflow as well as other sites and the answers all seem to deal with HTMLED and other dlls.  Also, I am using .Net's built-in installer - shouldn't it take care of installing the appropriate ActiveX controls (I assume WMP is in the .Net Framework).

Comment: No, the .NET installer most certainly doesn't install ActiveX components, it installs .NET framework components.  WMP is a Windows component, you can't install it.  So high odds for the Adobe stuff.

Comment: I looked at my installer and it does have the Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and also Interop.WMPLib.dll  Or is this not what we are talking about?

Comment: Sure, those are the .NET wrappers for these ActiveX components.  Just the wrappers, not the component itself.  You'll need to install at least Flash on that machine.

Comment: @Hans - bingo!  Your guess was correct, removing the Flash control removed the error.  Now I have to figure out how to implement the solution offered by @ Kratz below

Answer (score 1):

Like Hans says, it occurs because the programs you are using (WMP, Flash) are likely not installed on the target machine. The easiest thing you could do is simply try to detect this and warn the user that they need to install those programs for full functionality. So something like this:

```
Try
     Dim test as New WindowMediaPlayerControl 
Catch ex as exception
     MsgBox("The program requires Media Player to be installed.")
End Try
```

Then you could even set a flag that so that you can avoid loading the windows with the control on it, to avoid the user seeing the error.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if you are using ClickOnce deployment you can look here for the possibility of adding custom required installers to your program. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx

**Edit**: As Hans pointed out, my Try Catch is a little lazy above, you should always try to be very specific if you are trying to handle a particular error. Something like this for this case.

```
Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException When ex.Message.Contains("REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG")
```

Comment: This sounds doable except that I have inserted the control at design time, and I have had problems with doing it at run time.  For example, VB adds the control in the Declarations section where I can't add a Try Catch.  I will play with it, but if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: This is *evil* exception handling.  It turns everything that can go wrong into a "install it first" error message.  If it is already installed then the user has no hope of diagnosing the real problem.  **Never** hide the real exception message.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, you are correct. See my updated answer, do you believe that would be specific enough to show a "Not Installed" error?

Comment: @Chiwda, in my example I was just creating an instance of the control class to test and see if it works, not adding the Try..Catch to the actual code where it is being used. You could put something like the above in your startup forms `Load` event (at least if the control is not on the startup form). On a side note, there are probably better ways to see if the control you need is installed (registry check maybe), this is just a fast check to see if the control can be created.

Comment: Nope! Note solved and one of the reasons that the project is in limbo. :-(